# Creating grails scripts

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I am using grails 2.2.1 and i have a controller `myTestController` and an action `testMe` as

```
 package testOne
    class MyTestController {
      def testMe(){
       def testOne = new Test();
       testOne.save();
      }
    }
```

Now I want to create script for this.How can I do this please help

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to write a script to test a controller.  The Grails framework takes care of running tests via:

```
grails test-app
```

However, if you want to write Grails command line scripts, they go in the scripts/ directory of your  project.  For example code, look in the scripts/ directory of your Grails installation.  All the Grails command line scripts are there, like CreateDomainClass, GenerateAll, etc.